# How to add an object into an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an object into another object.

My previous post helped me on the array issue but I also need to add object into an object too.

I have something like

```
var temp = {};

for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++){
    console.log(test[i])
    console.log(product[i])
    temp.test[i] =product[i];
}
```

Both of console.log show values. However, I am getting

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"` for the `temp.test[i] =product[i]`

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks a lot

Comment: you have an empty object `{}`, it has no `test` property, did you mean to do: `var temp = {test:[]};`

Comment: Do you have problems understanding the error message? Or what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
var temp = {test:[], product:[]};
var test = ['a','v'];
var product = ['a2','v2'];
for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++){
    console.log(test[i])
    console.log(product[i])
    temp.test.push(product[i]);
}
```

You need to define your property test and product first and then push data.

But, you do not have to loop to insert every values. You can just set the whole collection in one shot.

```
var testCollection = ['Value 1', 'Value 2'];
var productCollection = ['Value 10', 'Value 20'];
var temp = {
    test:testCollection
  , product:productCollection
};
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, I mean to create the object property on the fly. I need to set new property with temp.test[i]. +1

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's answer would work if it is guaranteed that product.length >= test.length, or if you don't care about null entries being added. If you however want to fill the rest of the space with test's values instead of product's null values, then:

```
var temp = {test:[]};
var test = ['a','b','c'];
var product = ['d','e'];
for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++){
    console.log(test[i])
    console.log(product[i])
    if (i < product.length) {
        temp.test.push(product[i]);
    } else {
        temp.test.push(test[i]);
    }
}
```

But then again, I may be over thinking this and the answer is as simple as:

```
var temp = {
    test: product
};
```